# MPAndroidChart: Multiple markers at the same highlight

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to show on click, three `tooltips/markers`, with only one `dataset`.

Like in the below image:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: maybe this answer could solve your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/45276098/1083128

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that's not the answer i was looking for, what i want to know is how using pnly one dataset can i show trhee labels (one on the X axis, one on the Y axis and one on top of the resultant point of X and Y on the chart). The answer that you provide in the link is for when you have three datasets and show the label of each dataset when the user clicks

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `LineChart` and gave data to it.
and for multiple markers i have created a class implementing IMarker and created 2 Object
of a class i made for the information of each marker.
the way which the second marker is shown , depends on the position of first marker.
and i know it is not a good implementation maybe , but worked...

here is the code that worked for me:

```
public class ImageMakerTwoINOne implements IMarker {
    private Context mContext;
    public static final String TAG = "marker class";

    ObjectImage o1 = new ObjectImage();
    ObjectImage o2 = new ObjectImage();

    //constructor for initialization
    public ImageMakerTwoINOne(Context context, int drawableResourceId,int drawableResourceId2) {
        mContext = context;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            o1.drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(drawableResourceId, null);
            o2.drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(drawableResourceId2,null);
        } else {
             o1.drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(drawableResourceId);
             o2.drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(drawableResourceId2);
         }
    }


//////////////////////////////offset////////////////////////////
//setting the offsets by the users
public void setOffset(MPPointF offset,MPPointF offset2) {
    o1.offset = offset;
    o2.offset = offset2;
    //in case they were null :
    if (offset == null) o1.offset = new MPPointF();
    else if (offset2 == null) o2.offset = new MPPointF();
}
//setting the offsets by the user
public void setOffset(float offsetX, float offsetY , float offsetX2 , float offsetY2) {
    o1.offset.x = offsetX;
    o1.offset.y = offsetY;
    o2.offset.x = offsetX2;
    o2.offset.y = offsetY2;
}

@Override
public MPPointF getOffset() { return o2.offset; }

public MPPointF getOffset2(){ return o2.offset; }
////////////////////////size//////////////////////////////
//setting the size by the user
public void setSize(FSize size , FSize size2) {
    o1.size = size;
    o2.size = size2;
}
//getting the size of the objects
public FSize getSize1() { return o1.size; }
public FSize getSize2() { return o2.size; }
//////////////////chart///////////////////////////////////
//setting the charts
public void setChartView(Chart chart,Chart chart2) {
    o1.weakChart = new WeakReference<>(chart);
    o2.weakChart = new WeakReference<>(chart2);
}
//getting chart
public Chart getChartView1() {return o1.weakChart == null ? null : o1.weakChart.get(); }
public Chart getChartView2() { return o2.weakChart == null ? null : o2.weakChart.get(); }

//getting offset
@Override
public MPPointF getOffsetForDrawingAtPoint(float posX, float posY) {
    MPPointF offset = getOffset();
    Chart chart = getChartView1();

    float width1 = o1.size.width;
    float height1 = o1.size.height;
    if (width1==0.f){ width1 = o1.drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(); }
    if (height1==0.f){ height1 = o1.drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(); }
    MPPointF alaki = getOffsetForDrawingAtPoint2(posX,posY);
    return o1.offset;
}
public MPPointF getOffsetForDrawingAtPoint2(float posx , float posY){
    MPPointF offset = getOffset();
    Chart chart = getChartView1();

    float width1 = o2.size.width;
    float height1 = o2.size.height;
    if (width1==0.f){ width1 = o2.drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(); }
    if (height1==0.f){ height1 = o2.drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(); }
    return o2.offset;
}

@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

}

     @Override
     public void draw(Canvas canvas, float posX, float posY) {
        Canvas canvas2 = canvas;
        if (o1.drawable == null) return;
        MPPointF offset = getOffsetForDrawingAtPoint(posX,posY); //main position
        MPPointF offset2 = o2.offset; //main position obj 2
        float width = o1.size.width;
        float height = o1.size.height;
        if (width == 0.f) { width = o1.drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(); }
        if (height == 0.f) { height = o1.drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();}

        float width2 = 128;//o2.size.width;
        float height2 = 129;//o2.size.height;
        if (width == 0.f) { width = o2.drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(); }
        if (height == 0.f) { height = o2.drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();}

        o1.drawable.copyBounds(o1.drawableBoundsCache);
        o1.drawable.setBounds(
            o1.drawableBoundsCache.left,
            o1.drawableBoundsCache.top,
            (int) (o1.drawableBoundsCache.left+width),
            (int) (o1.drawableBoundsCache.top+height)
        );

        o2.drawable.copyBounds(o2.drawableBoundsCache);
        o2.drawable.setBounds(
            o2.drawableBoundsCache.left,
            o2.drawableBoundsCache.top,
            (int) (o2.drawableBoundsCache.left+width2),
            (int) (o2.drawableBoundsCache.top+height2)
        );

        int saveId = canvas.save();
        int saveId2 = canvas2.save();
    
        canvas.translate(posX + offset.x , posY + offset.y);
        o1.drawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas2.translate( 75 , -45 );

        o2.drawable.draw(canvas2);

        canvas2.restoreToCount(saveId2);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saveId);

        o1.drawable.setBounds(o1.drawableBoundsCache);
        o2.drawable.setBounds(o2.drawableBoundsCache);
    }
}


public class ObjectImage {
    public Drawable drawable;
    public MPPointF offset = new MPPointF();
    public WeakReference<Chart> weakChart;
    public FSize size = new FSize();
    public Rect drawableBoundsCache = new Rect();
}
```