# How to manage multiple markerview on same x,y values

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I used [MPChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) android library in my project and it was fulfilling my requirements but now in new enhancements in my project, I'm facing some issues.

1. How can I use markerview with direction arrow (Means if there is no space on the left side then markerview should be on the right side)?
2. In my project, it is possible to have multiple points using the same x,y values. So how can I display multiple markerview for these points with the same x,y values?

Using [this soltion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45276098/1083128)(with some modification), I'm able to get multiple markerview for same x,y values but they are overriding each other, So basically only one markerview is visible to users.

**Expectation**
[image]

**Result** - Point hide below markerview if there is not enough space on left. How can I move markerview to left/right/top/bottom of the point.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In regarding to your first point- In my project I implemented the `draw` method of MarkerView. For that I made an CustomMarkerView class, in which if there is no right space on graph (as in my project), then the markerview is displayed directing towards left. For that implement the below class.

```
public class CustomMarkerView extends MarkerView {

    private int uiScreenWidth;

    public CustomMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);
        uiScreenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, float posx, float posy) {
        // Checking and updating offsets.
        int w = getWidth();
        if ((uiScreenWidth - posx - w) < w) {
            posx -= w;
        }
        //  draw
        canvas.translate(posx, posy);
        draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(-posx, -posy);
    }
}
```

After this add this 
`CustomMarkerView mv = new CustomMarkerView(this, R.layout.your_markerview_layout);` in your class file where you implemented the chart.

Then, add `lineChart.setMarker(mv);` in your chart. If not according to your expectations, please tinker with the positions `posx and posy`.